# Adding External Javascript File in layout

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0

I have been trying to add one external javascript file in my module and alert message from  it. In source page link to javascript is showing but alert message is not coming.
Here is Template code.

```
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate()"></td>
```

Layout Code

```
 <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>Test/test.js</script></action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

and javascript file in js/Test/test.js

```
function validate(){
 alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: When you open page source, what path do you see? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes the path is correct but while clicking on the link, it is not showing the source which I wrote in test.js file.

Comment: If you open Developers tools and you write the function "validate();", something happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have uploaded the file to the right folder on the right server.

Clear your browser cache. Check if the server uses some external cache.

Make sure the file is readable by the web server.

Comment: Thanks Amasty. After clearing cache and deleting sessions several times the problem is fixed now.